# Redirect after successful sign in test giving error on my Rails app with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, integration-testing

I'm trying to use devise for the first time in a rails app and am loosely following the RoR tutorial by Michael Hartl. I'm trying to test logging in with valid information with

```
def setup
  @user = users(:michael)
end

...

test "login with valid information" do
  get new_user_session_path
  post new_user_session_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
  assert_redirected_to user_path(@user)
  follow_redirect!
  assert_template 'users/show'
  assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
  assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
end
```

but I am getting the error

```
FAIL["test_login_with_valid_information", UsersLoginTest, 2016-04-17 19:45:37 -0400]
test_login_with_valid_information#UsersLoginTest (1460936737.50s)
      Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>
      test/integration/users_login_test.rb:22:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
```

So it looks like it's having an issue with the line `assert_redirected_to user_path(@user)`. I know for a fact that this is what happens. I added

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  user_path(current_user) 
end
```

to my `application_controller.rb` and have verified it by testing through localhost. I've googled this error and have found a few posts with this same problem, but most are using something called factory girl and have solutions that don't seem to work in my situation. What's going on? Let me know if there is any extra information needed.

Edit: the 'michael' user is defined in /test/fixtures/users.yml

```
michael:
  first_name: Michael
  last_name: Example
  email: michael@example.com
  encrypted_password: <%= User.new.send(:password_digest, 'password') %>
  confirmed_at: Time.zone.now
```

Comment: Are you sure the login information is valid? If the login combination of `@user.email` and `password` does not work, the controller might be rendering the new user session path again with flash errors. That would explain the 200 status instead of a redirect.

Comment: Check my update. I have added a line in the test as well to verify that the user in the setup is valid with `assert @user.valid?` that passes, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the devise routes, you probably want to post to `user_sessions_path` instead of `new_user_sessions_path`. The latter is only defined for a `GET` action by default.

Second, you probably want to post with the user params. In other words:

```
post user_sessions_path, user: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
```